# Can’t use record’s discriminant within the record

Tags: record, ada

My code is below. The compiler won’t let me use the discriminant `var` to control the size of the string `name`.

```
procedure p is

   type int is range 1 .. 10;
   type my (var : int) is record
      name : string (1 .. var); -- this var here is bad, why?
   end record;

   hh : my(6);

begin
   put (hh.name);
end p;
```

The error messages are

```
p.adb:4:23: expected type "Standard.Integer"
p.adb:4:23: found type "int" defined at line 2
```

Comment: Why not use `Ada.Strings.Bounded`?

Comment: If you're using Gnat, the error message tells you exactly what's wrong. If you made `int` a subtype of `Integer` instead of a new type, you could discover the other errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to Ada strong typing.  Ada allows you to declare new integer and floating-point types which are not compatible with each other.  The original intent was to prevent accidentally using values with one meaning as if they had a totally unrelated meaning, e.g.

```
type Length is digits 15;  -- in meters
type Mass is digits 15;    -- in kilograms
L : Length;
M : Mass;

M := L;   -- error, caught at compile time
```

The compiler catches this statement that doesn't make any sense because a "mass" variable can't hold a length.  If everything were just `Float` or `Long_Float` the compiler wouldn't be able to catch it.

What you've done is to create another integer type, `int`.  As in the above example, values of your new type can't automatically be converted to `Integer`, which is the type of the index of `String`.  (`String` is actually defined as `array (Positive range <>) of Character with Pack;`, but `Positive` is a *subtype* of `Integer`, and values can be automatically converted between `Positive` and `Integer` since they are really subtypes of the same base type.)

Unfortunately, this isn't allowed either:

```
type my(var : int) is record
   name : string (1 .. Integer(var)); -- this var here is bad why?
end record;
```

because of an Ada rule that the discriminant has to appear alone in this context.  So your only option is to make `int` a subtype:

```
subtype int is Integer range 0 .. 10;
type my(var : int) is record
   name : string (1 .. var); -- this var here is bad why?
end record;
```